# Speeding up __array_finalize__ in a custom numpy class

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, constructor, python-internals

I have created a custom `numpy` class that I can give periodic boundary conditions to any given array with [`Periodic_Lattice()`](https://github.com/flipdazed/Hybrid-Monte-Carlo/blob/master/hmc/lattice.py) which can be used as follows

```
import numpy as np
from lattice import Periodic_Lattice
a = np.arange(100)
periodic_a = Periodic_Lattice(a)
print periodic_a[1001]

## -- End pasted text --
1
```

The method below `__array_finalize__` is taking a bizarre amount of time. I followed [this](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html#the-role-of-array-finalize) `scipy` tutorial on subclassing and wrote the following constructor.

```
def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
    """ ndarray.__new__ passes __array_finalize__ the new object, 
    of our own class (self) as well as the object from which the view has been taken (obj). 
    """
    if obj is None: return

    try: # this is a way faster method of doing this
        self.lattice_shape   = obj.lattice_shape        # getattr(obj, 'lattice_shape', obj.shape)
        self.lattice_dim     = obj.lattice_dim          # getattr(obj, 'lattice_dim', len(obj.shape)) 
        self.lattice_spacing = obj.lattice_spacing      # getattr(obj, 'lattice_spacing', None)
    except: 
        self.lattice_shape   = obj.shape
        self.lattice_dim     = len(self.lattice_shape)
        self.lattice_spacing = None
    pass
```

Please see [`Periodic_Lattice()`](https://github.com/flipdazed/Hybrid-Monte-Carlo/blob/master/hmc/lattice.py) for the full class which is just `36` lines of code excluding comments

I achieved significant speed gains by dropping `getattr()` and using the `try/except` method but any alternatives are welcomed